# How to check the bit of value in pandas dataframe is set or not?

Tags: python

i Have a dataframe like

```
data = {
  "calories": [420, 380, 390....],
  "duration": [50, 40, 45...]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I NEED TO COUNT the total number of value in certain column that

```
a)if bit 0  is set in certain df['column']
b)if bit 1  is set in certain df['column']
c)if bit 2  is set in certain df['column']
d)if bit 3  is set in certain df['column']
```

i am using like

```
df.loc[df['column'] == 2 || df['column'] == 3 || df['column'] == 6.....].count()
```

to find out how many element in that column that have BIT 2 is SET

thanks

Comment: Do you need the number of data points in a column or the number of times a certain data point comes up in a series? Like the number of times 380 shows up in ```df["calories"]``` is 5 times or there are 300 total data points in ```df["calories"]```

Comment: @lwashington27 i need to count how many value in df["calories"]
is bit 1,2,3,4 SET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bit-wise arithmetic to test whether bit 1 (which is == 2) is set:

```py
df['column'] & 2 != 0
```

and then just sum the true/false results:

```py
sum(df['column'] & 2 != 0)
```